# How to call a tableviewcell on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created a custom tableview cell in which i am displaying the values fetched from xml parsing.The tableview cell enters in the first case i.e the 0th case and displays the current weather condition. i have button on my tableview cell.When i click on that button the tableview cell should enter into the second case of my tableview i.e case 1 and display the forecast condition of weather. i have done  this .But my tableview always displays the same row in every cell. it does not enter into the case 1 .What may be the problem.Thanks

Comment: post some code of table view cell method.

Comment: Rani, the problem seems to be in the code. Post the code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you've updated the table view with the new data after the button click, you can simply reload it.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i want to call the second row of the tableview on button click

Comment: What do you mean by call the second row?

Comment: i mean i am having 4 cases in my tableview cellfor row at indexpath method but when i put breakpoint and run only my 1st case is getting called